# Excel count occurrences of a value

Tags: vba, excel

I have been given data which is associated by postal code.

I need to count the number of occurrences of certain values in certain columns. Sample data is below.

```
Survey# PostCode
1       2136
1       2136
2       136
2       2136
1       2137
2       2137
```

I would like to take this data and produce this type of excel workbook:

```
Postal Code Survey #1   Survey #2   Survey #3   Survey #4
2136        2           2           0           0
2137        1           1           0           0
```

I have tried to write code to produce this by using a while loop and the following code. The code works without the while loop.

If you comment out the while look it works, however, I have to select the postal codes I want and then run the macro... it works well when I do this, it adds up all the occurrences of the 1,2,3, or 4 and then places these count values in the appropriate columns.

What I want is for it to run through the column add up all of the occurrences with one postal code (2136), stop and add in the count to the columns.  Then begin again counting the occurrences of the next postal code until it gets to the next one and then stop - add in counts.

```
Sub sort_PC_CPE()

Dim cell As Object
Dim count As Integer
Dim count1 As Integer
Dim count2 As Integer
Dim SV1Count As Integer
Dim SV2Count As Integer
Dim SV3Count As Integer
Dim SV4Count As Integer
Dim ofset As Integer
Dim newVal As Object

'Dim origvalue As Object

count = 0
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
SV1Count = 0
SV2Count = 0
SV3Count = 0
SV4Count = 0
ofset = -1

' if you use the for each cell... and then highlight the cells with the same postal code, this works (also commenting out the while loop)
'For Each cell In Selection

    While cell.Offset(ofset, 0).Value = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(ofset, 0).Select
        ofset = ofset - 1
    Wend

       'the following works well so long as you manually highlight the cells you want. 
        If cell.Offset(0, -3).Value = 1 Then

            SV1Count = SV1Count + 1
            cell.Offset(-count, 1).Value = SV1Count

            count = count + 1

        ElseIf cell.Offset(0, -3).Value = 2 Then

            SV2Count = SV2Count + 1
            cell.Offset(-count, 2).Value = SV2Count
            count = count + 1

        ElseIf cell.Offset(0, -3).Value = 3 Then

            SV3Count = SV3Count + 1
            cell.Offset(-count, 3).Value = SV3Count
            count = count + 1

        ElseIf cell.Offset(0, -3).Value = 4 Then

            SV4Count = SV4Count + 1
            cell.Offset(-count, 4).Value = SV4Count
            count = count + 1





    End If




End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post more about your question? Does the code produce an error or does it not give the correct result?

Comment: Why not just use a Pivot Table?

Comment: becasue I am placing this into a GIS and I need the count in the columns.  If you can use a Pivot table to add in values, I will try it - what do you think.
@ChipsLetten - I have added a little explanation - I hope this helps.  thank you for taking your time and looking at this for me.

Comment: Hi @Kyle - the pivot table works a treat.  Might there be any code to implement this for my problem.  This is purely an academic exercise now as you have provided the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a countifs?

I dropped your sample into a new sheet in column A and B, in column D I put 2136 in row 1 and 2137 in row 2. If you have a large number of postcodes, copy the whole column from the source and paste into column D then click Data and remove Duplicates to get your distinct list.

E1 is this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,COLUMN(E1)-4,$B:$B,$D1)
```

Drag across 4 columns and then down 2 rows

results:

2136    2   2   0   0

2137    1   1   0   0